# How to add Add view in Web view?

Tags: android, webview, admob

Here is my web view with progress bar.Progress bar goes disappear when after loading web view.It contains in linear layout.My problem is ,I want to add view in bottom.I tried.Please help me

```
<android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    tools:context=".MainActivity">

    <LinearLayout
        android:id="@+id/liProgressContainer"
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:orientation="vertical"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintLeft_toLeftOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintRight_toRightOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent">

            <ProgressBar
            android:id="@+id/progressBar"
            style="@style/Widget.AppCompat.ProgressBar.Horizontal"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:background="#FFFFFF" />

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/tvLoadingPercentage"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:background="#FFFFFF" />

    </LinearLayout>

    <WebView
        android:id="@+id/webView"
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="0dp"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintLeft_toLeftOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintRight_toRightOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/liProgressContainer">

    </WebView>


</android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout>
```

Here is my add view code:(I want to add it to"alignParentBottom" )

```
<com.google.android.gms.ads.AdView
        xmlns:ads="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
        android:id="@+id/adView"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
        android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
        ads:adSize="BANNER"
        ads:adUnitId="ca-app-pub-3940256099942544/6300978111">
    </com.google.android.gms.ads.AdView>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are using a coordinator layout. In a coordinator layout, **alignParentBottom** does not work. You can either use **RelativeLayout** for the **alignParentBottom**, or edit your code to match the **CoordinatorLayout's** requirements.

Here is the code where a *RelativeLayout is the root layout:*

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
tools:context=".MainActivity">

<LinearLayout
    android:id="@+id/liProgressContainer"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    android:layout_centerInParent="true">

        <ProgressBar
        android:id="@+id/progressBar"
        style="@style/Widget.AppCompat.ProgressBar.Horizontal"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:background="#FFFFFF" />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/tvLoadingPercentage"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:background="#FFFFFF" />

</LinearLayout>

<WebView
    android:id="@+id/webView"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:layout_below="@id/liProgressContainer"/>

<com.google.android.gms.ads.AdView
    xmlns:ads="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    android:id="@+id/adView"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
    android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
    ads:adSize="BANNER"
    ads:adUnitId="ca-app-pub-3940256099942544/6300978111">
</com.google.android.gms.ads.AdView>
```

Now the AdView will be displayed at the bottom of the page.

Answer (score 0):

To align AdView to bottom of layout you can do the following

```
   <com.google.android.gms.ads.AdView xmlns:ads="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    android:id="@+id/adView"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    ads:adSize="BANNER"
    ads:adUnitId="ca-app-pub-3940256099942544/6300978111"
    ads:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent">

</com.google.android.gms.ads.AdView>
```

[image: Adview align parent bottom]

Having set the remaining constraints of elements as mentioned in your question, and webview width and height as match parents, the layout will be something like below.

[image]

Do check if this is the layout you are aiming for.